# PHP array checkbox and radio default value

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, radio-button

I have the code below in my wordpress options page. I can't define the default values for checkbox and radio.

```
array(
    "name" => "Post Thumbnails",
    "desc" => "Choose if you want to display <strong>post thumbnails</strong> or not.",
    "id" => $shortname."_post_thumbs",
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "std" => "checked"      
),  

array(
        "name" => "Example",
        "desc" => " The Descriptions",
        "id" => $shortname."_case_thumb",
        "type" => "radio",
        "options" => array("nothumb" => " Display nothing", "defthumb" => " Display thumbnail"),
        "std" => "nothumb"      
    ),
```

For the checkbox tried also `"std" => "true"` and `"std" => " "`... but didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: add only checked at "std" => "checked"

Comment: Can you tell us the context you are using this in? Like in a particular Wordpress Theme? or using a particular framework?

Comment: Chacha102 I am using this in wordpress options page.

Comment: Can't you just use checked => "checked" as in html?

Comment: In a quick browse around http://codex.wordpress.org I can't find any "options page" related function that takes arrays of the type you give here. Can you clarify what function you are passing these arrays to, as the arrays themselves do not mean anything to PHP, only to that function.